# Android Facebook SDK 3.0 logout

Tags: android, facebook

I have an app which uses the Facebook SDK 3.0 and I'd like to make it possible, that a user can logout from facebook in my app.

Is there any possibility, to logout or force a login dialog?

I tried to use the `authorize()` method from the older facebook sdk but I'm not able to merge it with the session things from the new sdk, so I have to do it all with session from sdk 3.0 or with the Facebook class from the older sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to force a logout of the native Facebook app via your app.

Comment: in com.facebook.widget.LoginButton, the LoginClickListener handles the Login and Logout for Facebook, so is it not possible to customize Logout ?

Comment: thats for logging out of your app, not logging out of the native Facebook app

Answer (score 0):

I do that into my app, on the onCreate() method, you should do something like that

```
if (Session.getActiveSession() != null) {
Session.getActiveSession().closeAndClearTokenInformation();
 }
Session.setActiveSession(null);
```

You can also save Token Information anywhere, and then call closeAndClearTokenInformation() again.

Hope this help.